# How to show both updated and loaded text in a recyclerview?

Tags: java, android

I am trying to make a Daily expense style app for a departmental store, the problem scenario is like this:

> Imagine a customer deposited 500/= and he bought goods of 750/=, that
>   means he has 250/= of Due amount, and in the next day he gave the rest
>   amount. Now I want to keep track of every transaction, like: the first
>   day he deposited:250/= , due: 150/= again in the next day deposited:
>   500/= , due: 50/= for every specific customer.
>
> I already added the due and deposit amount in two different lists and
>   showing them on a recycler view, but it is not giving the list for a
>   specific customer, the list stores amount of every customers. But i
>   want the history for specific customer.

```
dueList.add(dueAmount);
depositList.add(depositAmount);
```

// and showing them on the onBindHolder method of recyclerview

```
 historyHolder.dueHistoryTV.setText("Due History: "+DetailsActivity.dueList);
 historyHolder.depositHistoryTV.setText("Due History: "+DetailsActivity.depositList);
```

> This is showing like this: Due History: [200,250] Deposit History:
>   [100,150] but whenever I click on another customer it takes the
>   previous values with it like lets say the new user has 500/= deposit
>   and 100/=due, my result shows: Due History: [200,250,100]  Deposit
>   History: [100,150,500].
>
> But I want to show the list for specific users like this:  Due
>   History: Day 1:100, Day 2: 200 Deposit History: Day 1: 500, Day 2: 100

Comment: Where are you storing the data?

Comment: In Room Sqlite.

Comment: And are you storing/retrieving the data using a user id of some sort?

Comment: Hmm yes , I am keeping an different ID for each user.

Comment: And are you using that to get the info of each user? Please provide how you are getting specific user info

Comment: @Query("select * from Customer where id = :id")

    List<Customer> findDetails(int id);

This is how I got the details by using ID.